# Convert CWnd* to myControl*

Tags: c++, casting, mfc, controls, cwnd

I am trying to convert a `CWnd*` pointer to a custom control pointer. The custom control just extends `CEdit`. Below is what I have. `pWnd` was passed in. it is a `CWnd*`.

```
calEdit* test = (calEdit*)pWnd->GetDlgItem(pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID());
```

When I try to debug and see what the value of test is, none of its members can be evaluated. The `CWnd*` is definitely not the problem.

To be sure that the `CWnd*` is pointing to the control I want, I did `pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID()`, and the ID matches the expected control.

Comment: It seems that you could simply go for `calEdit* test = (calEdit*)pWnd`, as what you are doing is getting the ID of pWnd, and then getting the CWnd pointer of this ID, that is pWnd.

Comment: Besides from the debugger unable to evaluate the members, does the code work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `CEdit *pEdit = dynamic_cast<CEdit*>(pWnd)`

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
CEdit *pEdit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit*>(pWnd);
if (pEdit != nullptr)
  // Do something here
```